# Application locked in the read() of a serial port device

Tags: serial-port

OS Linaro on arm machine.
I'm writing a C console application that communicates with a USB device that exposes a virtual serial port profile.
Sometimes happens that the USB device is disconnected (and then reconnected): my application is locked forever in the read() call.
I'm wondering why the read() does not return with any kind of error code.
Is it a matter of the serial device driver?

How can I detect the lock and, first of all, how can I exit from read() call?

Comment: what happens if you run `cat /dev/that_usb_serial_device` and then unplug the thingy?

Comment: it immediately returns `cat: /dev/ttyACM0: Resource temporarily unavailable` , before unplug!

Comment: Nothing? No EOF? Can you share with us the relevant part of the code?

Comment: The cat command use this : https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/safe-read.c
(rw=read safe_rw = safe_read, tricky :)...) And cat, looks like working.